# wxPython wx.TextCtrl tab width

Tags: python, wxpython, wxtextctrl

How to set the Tab width to 4 rather than 8 in wx.TextCtrl?
if not possible what is the alternative to use instead of wx.TextCtrl?

**Note:**
mytxtCtrl.setDefaultStyle(wx.TextAttr().setTabs([...]) not working!

Comment: Have you noticed that [`SetTabs`](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.TextAttr.html#SetTabs) are set in tenths of millimeter?

Comment: BTW: Default does not seem to match 8 spaces either. It is some fixed width.

Comment: I know that and it works just in rich-text-ctrl. it seems that pure textCtrl doesn't handle it. your sample use rich-text-ctrl. thanks.

Comment: Well, my sample uses `wx.TextCtrl` with `wx.TE_RICH` style. Not `wx.richtext.RichTextCtrl`. These are not the same. The later would probably handle this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SetTabs`](http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.TextAttr.html#SetTabs) are set in tenths of millimeter. Not sure why, that is brutal to work with!

```
import wx

TAB = 4

TEST = "".join([" "*i*TAB + "|\n" + "\t"*i + "|\n" for i in range(1, 30, 2)])

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_TAB | wx.TE_RICH | wx.TE_MULTILINE)

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.text, 1, wx.ALL | wx.EXPAND)

        self.text.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.SetTabs)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
        self.Show()

        self.text.SetValue(TEST)

    def SetTabs(self, e):  
        pixel_width_in_mm = 25.4 / wx.ScreenDC().GetPPI()[0]
        space_width_in_pixels = self.text.GetTextExtent(" ")[0]
        tab_width_in_tenth_of_mm = (10 * TAB * space_width_in_pixels * pixel_width_in_mm)
        textctrl_width_in_mm = (10 * self.text.GetSize()[0] * (1 / pixel_width_in_mm))
        nr_of_tabs = int(textctrl_width_in_mm / tab_width_in_tenth_of_mm)
        tabs = [int((i+1)*tab_width_in_tenth_of_mm) for i in range(nr_of_tabs)]
        attr = wx.TextAttr()
        attr.SetTabs(tabs)
        self.text.SetDefaultStyle(attr)

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
    wx.TextCtrl(panel, pos = (10, 10), size = (40, 20))
```

Comment: My apologies for trying to help. What do you mean by Tab width then?

Comment: let the answer to whom know what is tab character (\t)!